# Finding gateway discussion groups from online posts

Tags: conditional-probability, social-network, social-science

I'm looking at online discussion group participation and I'm trying to determine whether posting to group A increases the likelihood of subsequently posting to group B empirically (is A a gateway group to B?), but I'm not sure how to do this and I can't seem to find methods papers or papers with good methods sections showing me how to.

I know how to so simple conditional probability estimates (if a user posts to A, what is the chance of also posting to B), but I don't know how to do the analysis to determine how much more likely a user is to post to B if they posted to A previously than if they post to any other group or no group at all before. I assume that I would have to compare A -> B vs. any two random groups and/or vs. posting in any random group.

Could someone point me to a paper or method? Thanks.

For some background, I'm looking at about 10M groups and 100M users with the average user posting to a little more than 10 groups but the median is 2 groups.

Since I don't have the computational power to go through all of the user-group combinations and I only want to know (I think) if a user posts to group A first and only thereafter posts to B, I have culled the data so that only the first instances of each posting in each group for a user are present. I do have the original user, group, and date-time posting information if needed (though no information about post content).

I appreciate any help including RTFM if there is a fabulous manual.

Comment: This looks like a social network (of groups or of posters?) Maybe add tag [tag:social-network]

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Done, added social-science for good measure.